# How can i get the name of an emitted event through the event abi (log entry, topics) of solidity?

Tags: solidity, events, web3j, abi

I want to get the name of an emitted event from my contract using the [event abi](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#events) and web3j.

This is the contract i'm using as an example for this question:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;
contract NumberContract2{

uint256 number;

event newNumberStored(uint256 number);
event calledRequestNumberFunction();

function storeNumber(uint256 num) public
{
    number = num;
    emit newNumberStored(num);
}

function requestNumber() public returns (uint256)
{
    emit calledRequestNumberFunction();
    return number;
}
```

}

This is where i hope to get the information out of (see [event abi](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#events)):

```
 topics[0]:
 keccak(EVENT_NAME+"("+EVENT_ARGS.map(canonical_type_of).join(",")+")")
```

I created a listener in my code that prints out every event that gets emitted:

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, numberContract2.getContractAddress().substring(2));
    web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(log -> System.out.println(log));
```

When an event is emitted (*in this case through storeNumber(1234)*) it prints out the following:

```
Log{removed=false, logIndex='0x0', transactionIndex='0x0', transactionHash='0xde7ea1ed3ca6cae5e3fb2478cc0212a2fc4d71c4c82b2edabde61c88629f667c', blockHash='0xb86c2af91b32492ee06e7ca632a56b973dfb5bbb4af045c627727547819c298f', blockNumber='0x89', address='0x820dbe91d4ee217b518b7be2cd7c30ea47e5ee1e', data='0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d2', type='mined', topics=[0xa7f1c945da9b165cf9d2d173e7bf823eb59569ecffef3d150fe6c74b6e78933f]}
```

Which is kind of what i expected, but how can i get the name of the event now? Is it even possible? If not is there another way to do it?

When i look at the transaction log in remix it clearly shows the name of the event but i don't see that in the log that i print out.

```
    [ { "from": "0x820Dbe91D4Ee217B518B7BE2CD7c30ea47e5ee1E", "topic": "0xa7f1c945da9b165cf9d2d173e7bf823eb59569ecffef3d150fe6c74b6e78933f", "event": "newNumberStored", "args": { "0": "1234", "number": "1234" } } ]
```

My goal in the end is to add a listener that listens to all events, and filter them by name later (outside of web3j).